# Why my adView is half in screen area and helf out?

Tags: android, android-layout, adview

I added adview to my app programatically and I want it to be added/removed (if user make a in-app purchase) bellow my recycler view. I intentionally put mu Recycler view and adview in a Linear layout (container), which I am referencing in code and adding/removing the adview. However, when I tried it, my adview is half visible in the screen and there is space on the right of it like this:
[image]

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myMainRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar">
</include>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/myAdContainer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="No Shopping Items yet"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

    <com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
        fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_down"/>
```

This is the code that adds the adview:

```
// does the user have the premium upgrade?
            mIsRemoveAdds = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADDS);
            if(!mIsRemoveAdds) {
                //play ads
                mAdView = new AdView(MainActivity.this);
                mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
                mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                adContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myAdContainer);
                //check if the adview is already added (count ==2) otherwise added
                int i = adContainer.getChildCount();
                if(! (i > 1)) {
                    adContainer.addView(mAdView, params);
                }
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"no premium",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //remove ads
                if(mAdView != null) {
                    adContainer.removeView(mAdView);
                }
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"premium",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/myAdContainer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Remove weight and weightSum.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it dies not help. Actually, removing the weight and weightSum makes the adview to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/myAdContainer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The issue I found here is, You are allocating a weights of 100 to the ViewGroup [LinearLayout] and utilising only 50 of it for the View [RecyclerView]. so the above solution of utilising the entire allocated space of the viewGroup should help it displaying it fully.

Comment: This won't work for my purposes, as I don't want all of the space to be taken of by my recycling view. In this case my adview won't be seen at all when I add it by code.